# C++/QT выполнения функций в отдельном файле

Tags: c++, qt

В `main.cpp` имеется функция с телом

```
MainWindow::HelloWorld(){
    std::count << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

Данную функцию хочу вызвать в другом файле к примеру `foo.cpp.`
При этом только `main.cpp` знает, что `foo.cpp` существует с помощью `#include <foo.h>`

Comment: Чтобы вызвать функцию явно, нужно иметь доступное объявление этой функции в точке вызова.

Comment: @alexolut а можно послать какой-то сигнал, чтобы вызвать функцию? Т.е emit и соединить их с помощью connect();?

Comment: для `connect` всё равно нужно иметь оба прототипа. Это ж всё по сути реализация `callback` функций.

Comment: @alexolut Ну что вы, для `connect` не обязательно видеть прототипы

Comment: @alexolut я ведь не могу никак дать доступ `foo.cpp` в `main.cpp`, если доступ уже прописан в `main.cpp` для `foo.cpp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы будите вынуждены объявить класс `MainWindow` в файле `foo.cpp`:

```
class MainWindow{
public:
    void HelloWorld();
};

void Foo(){
    MainWindow test_obj;
    test_obj.HelloWorld();
}
```

Но такой подход не корректен изначально. Предлагаю пользоваться классическим методом создания файлов.
Файл `foo.h` содержит объявление класса `Foo`:

```
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO

class Foo{
public:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
    void HelloWorld();
}

#endif // FOO
```

Файл `foo.cpp` содержит описание класса `Foo`:

```
#include <Foo.h>
#include <iostream>

Foo::Foo(){}

Foo::~Foo(){}

void Foo::HelloWorld(){
    std::count << "Hello World" << std::endl;
}
```

Файл `main.cpp` подключает файл объявления `foo.h`, создает и использует объект класса `Foo`:

```
#include <Foo.h>

int main(){
    Foo foo_obj;
    foo_obj.HelloWorld();
    retrun 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сигналы и слоты Qt можно связывать анонимно по их строковым сигнатурам. То есть не имея полного объявления классов связываемых объектов. Вы можете сделать так:

```
bool connectHelloWorld(QObject * sender, QObject * receiver)
{
    return QObject::connect(  sender  , SIGNAL(sayHello())
                            , receiver, SLOT(HelloWorld()) );
}
```

Это работает потому как аргумент макросов `SIGNAL` и `SLOT` интерпретируется как строка, посмотрите их реализацию. Далее эти строки обрабатываются внутри мета-объектной подсистемы Qt и в результате мы имеем связанные сигналы. Естественно сигналы и слоты должны быть [правильно объявлены](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/signalsandslots.html) и обработаны утилитой `moc`.

Comment: И получаем ошибку времени выполнения потому что не можем найти целевую функцию?

Comment: а если второй файл foo.cpp из которого хочу вызвать функцию из main.cpp, не является обьектной системой qt?

Comment: @alexolut Это да, вопрос же был как вызвать, а не как не получить ошибку времени выполнения.

Comment: @Insider Так слоты работать не будут, я ж написал про это. В foo.cpp вы должны реализвать класс-наследник QObject, все как напимано по ссылке.

Comment: хорошо, как вы думаете, куда дописать класс наследник QObject в такой код

`namespace disti
{
class MapViewClass : public ComponentBase

{
public:`

Comment: @Insider Куда что дописывать можете решать только вы, так как только вы имеете на руках проект. Если у вас есть с этим затруднения, задайте еще один вопрос.